Micronaut Kotlin: real bean is not replaced by mock
I must mock a service in micronaut, but in my test I see that real bean is still used.
@MicronautTest(startApplication = false)
class StatsCommandHandlerTest {


    @Inject
    lateinit var wordCountService: WordCountService


    @MockBean(WordCountService::class)
    fun wordCountService(): WordCountService{
        return mockk(relaxed = true)
    }

   
    @Test
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    fun statsHandlerExistsTest() {
        every {
            wordCountService.getWordStat(50)
        } returns mapOf(
            "test" to 2,
            "test1" to 3
        )
      //OTHER TEST CODE IS OMITTED 
    }

I read on the internet mockk is better than mockito -so I used it, but behaviour is the same. Chat GPT gives some fake data. Can someone help me with it?
